# Background image not scaling properly on iOS

Tags: html, ios, css, ipad, scale

Problem is that background images are not scaling properly on iOS devices, it's a responsive site and at least on desktop browsers it does scale great even on very small resolutions.. But when I test on iPhone/iPad it doesn't seem to be working that way.

The page is http://litoplas.net16.net/como.html (it's an internal presentation for meetings and phorums, it won't be a public link, and my customer wants his representatives to use iPads, which is the reason solving this is very important).

Here's an example of the CSS of a section I'm using with a background image:

```
.corte {
background: url(../images/corte.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
background-size: cover;
padding-bottom: 30%;
```

}

And as I said, the background images are scaling nicely on desktop browsers...They won't do the same on iOs!

Thanks in advance guys, I spent a lot  of time searching and trying to figure this out, hopefully you'll have some answers for me! :)

Comment: I've noticed PNG images scale better than JPGs, try saving one as a PNG and see if there's a difference.

Answer (score 14):

It appears to be your shorthand rule: `background: url(../images/bannercalidad.jpg) no-repeat fixed;`

More specifically it is the `background-attachment: fixed` that is causing the issues.  If I add a new rule of `background-attachment: scroll` then the image is no longer zoomed way far in to the upper-left corner.  This may not solve all your problems but it will get you on the right path.

Comment: thanks for this - i tried it and it worked on the iPad for me. @fernker

Comment: @MJCoder if this was the answer, please mark it so. Both so that the person helps you gets points and so that other people know this solved your problem.

Comment: Please try to close a question properly by accepting the answer that worked.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have the following rule applied for each `<section>` like so:

`background-size: 100% auto;`

This fixed the problem for me using an iOS 7 simulator.

Answer (score 1):

`background-attachment: scroll;` worked for me. You should accept @Fernker's answer.